# Restore wordpress theme custom css from duplicator database backup

Tags: css, database, wordpress, wordpress-theming, database-restore

I accidentally overwrote my sites custom CSS found in the theme options.

After some research I found out that the custom CSS is stored in the database.

I have a backup of the database from the duplicator plugin, however the backed up code looks different from the one found in phpmyadmin.

Current database from phpMyAdmin:

```
a:204:{s:8:"last_tab";s:2:"33";s:15:"body-background";a:7:{s:16:"background-color";s:0:"";s:17:"background-repeat";s:0:"";
```

Duplicator plugin backup database:

```
a:204:{s:8:\"last_tab\";s:1:\"5\";s:15:\"body-background\";a:7:{s:16:\"background-color\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"background-repeat\";s:0:\"\";
```

As you can see there are backslashes on the backup code.

Any ideas of how I might be able to restore just the custom CSS from the options in the backup database?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better technical answer here but the clunky, non-technical way is to set up your site locally (hopefully you already have this?) and import the backed up database, copy out the custom css and then copy that back to the live site.

Comment: I am using MAMP building the site locally, I made some progress after creating the backup. 

Is there no way to just copy paste the theme options from database to database?

Comment: Great! Then you can set up a new db locally based on the backed up db you have and grab the old custom css code from wp-admin.

Comment: Ok!

I know some basic stuff but I am learning as I go along.

Do I just import the db backup on myphpadmin?

Comment: Since you have you local site you simply: 1. create a new db locally with your db backup 2. Update wp-config for your site to point to this new db temporarily 3. login to wp-admin and get Appearance/Customise css code, then 4. Copy this css back to your live site 5. You could also add it to your local db when you switch back to the original db, not sure how you want to handle this

Comment: It worked!


Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool! I'll post my comment as an answer instead and you can vote it up if you like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have you local site you can:

1. create a new db locally with your db backup
2. Update wp-config for your site to point to this new db temporarily
3. login to wp-admin and get Appearance/Customise css code, then
4. Copy this css back to your live site
5. I recommend then exporting your live db back to local so the change is applied and you have the latest version to work with

Of course you could do a SQL command to replace the record but this seems like too much work for this.